# How can I filter sensitive data being recorded in calls to Watchdog

Tags: 7, security, log-messages

I have sensitive data that is sent to a Drupal instance and I don't want it to be logged. I can filter out sensitive values with simple string replacements for my own calls to `watchdog()`, but for PHP errors and other modules making `watchdog()` calls, the data may be logged and this needs to be filtered too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're dealing with the dblog module, this is a workable solution:

1. Disable the dblog module
2. Copy `dblog_watchdog` into your own module's `hook_watchdog` implementation
3. Wrap each of the appropriate database field entries with your function to sanitise the string, e.g.

   ```
   Database::getConnection('default', 'default')->insert('watchdog')
     ->fields(array(
       'uid' => $log_entry['uid'],
       'type' => mymodule_sanitise(drupal_substr($log_entry['type'], 0, 64)),
   ...
   ```

If you have other watchdog modules in use, you'll need a copy/edited `hook_watchdog` version for each of them too.